# Overloaded operators for std::bind placeholders

Tags: c++, boost, stl, operator-overloading, bind

`boost::bind` overloads several operators for its placeholders:

> For convenience, the function objects produced by `bind` overload the logical not operator `!` and the relational and logical operators `==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `&&`, `||`.

For example, this allows me to pass `_1 == desired_value` as a predicate to STL algorithms.

Unfortunately, `std::bind` does not seem to overload these operators :(

1. Why is that?
2. What is a good workaround to simulate `_1 == desired_value` with `std::bind`?

Comment: I think it is because C++11 has lambda, and therefore I don't see why you would need such operators instead. (wll this comment seems to be an answer).

Comment: @Nawaz `std::bind` is part of TR1 which predates C++11 by 6 years.

Comment: Fred, But **now** it is a part of `std::`, not `tr1::`

Comment: You can always create your own placeholders, and overload operators for those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, Boost.Bind only overloads those operators for the placeholders because the original Boost Lambda Library, which Boost.Bind is an improvement of, did (Boost.Bind is obsolete thanks to Boost.Phoenix, btw). `std::bind`'s placeholders are only intended for exactly that purpose, as placeholders for arguments to `std::bind`.

As a workaround, use polymorphic functors:

```
struct compare_equal{
  template<class LHS, class RHS>
  bool operator()(LHS&& lhs, RHS&& rhs){ // assume bool return
    return std::forward<LHS>(lhs) == std::forward<RHS>(rhs);
  }
};

// ...
auto bound = std::bind(compare_equal(), _1, desired_value);
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/fmhlE)

Comment: @Nawaz: And you just illustrated the exact problem I'm trying to tell you about in your comments. I don't use any specific type in my code, making it full generic. The lambda needs you to tell exactly the types that will be used.

Comment: @Xeo Don't the c++1y lambdas do that? Personally, I like Boost Phoenix a lot better than c++11 lambdas. They usually are shorter and easier to read with less garbage syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could always overload these operators for the placeholders yourself, for example `operator<`:

```
struct less12
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    bool operator()(const T& a, const U& b) const
    {
        return a < b;
    }
};

less12 operator<(decltype(_1), decltype(_2))
{
    return less12();
}


struct less21
{
    template<typename U, typename T>
    bool operator()(const U& b, const T& a) const
    {
        return a < b;
    }
};

less21 operator<(decltype(_2), decltype(_1))
{
    return less21();
}


template<typename T>
struct lessa1
{
    const T& a;

    template<typename U>
    bool operator()(const U& b) const
    {
        return a < b;
    }
};

template<typename T>
lessa1<T> operator<(const T& a, decltype(_1))
{
    lessa1<T> result = {a};
    return result;
}


template<typename U>
struct less1b
{
    const U& b;

    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& a) const
    {
        return a < b;
    }
};

template<typename U>
less1b<U> operator<(decltype(_1), const U& b)
{
    less1b<U> result = {b};
    return result;
}
```

Here is a usage example, compared with binders (custom `less12` vs `std::less`) and lambda syntax:

```
template<typename Iterator>
void quicksort(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    // ...
    auto m = std::partition(begin + 1, end, _1 < *begin);

    auto m = std::partition(begin + 1, end, std::bind(less12(), _1, *begin));

    auto m = std::partition(begin + 1, end, std::bind(std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type>(), _1, *begin));

    auto m = std::partition(begin + 1, end, [begin](const typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type& x) { return x < *begin; } );
    // ...
}
```

Really looking forward to [N3421](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm) and polymorphic lambdas here :)

Answer (score 0):

> std::bind does not seem to overload these operators?
>   Why is that?

Because C++11 added lambdas which provide the same, if not better, conveniences to produce anonymous functor objects.

> What is a good workaround to simulate _1 == desired_value with std::bind?

std::bind is not used to simulate the behavior. Use C++11 lambdas to implement the answer to your question:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](int i) -> bool { return i == desired_value; });
```

Please note that you don't need the "-> bool" syntax if you are using a fairly recent compiler that can derive the return type.

If you don't want to or can't use C++11 lambdas, then you can create a non-anonymous functor like this:

```
bool IsDesiredValue (int i) {
    return (i == desired_value);
}
std::vector<int>::iterator i = std::find_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), IsDesiredValue);
```

For another example, here is a use of C++11 lambdas being used to create an anonymous functor to sort a vector by a value of a type:

```
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [](const Foo& i, const Foo& j) -> bool { return i.myValue < j.myValue; });
```

An alternative, non-lambda version would be:

```
struct myclass {
  bool operator() (const Foo& i, const Foo& j) { return (i.myValue < j.myValue); }
} myobject;
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myobject);
```

And here's how you would do the same sort using boost's operator overload:

```
std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), boost::bind(&MyClass::myValue, _1) < boost::bind(&MyClass::myValue, _2))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because C++11 has lambda, and therefore I don't see why you would need such operators instead.

Comment: No polymorphic lambdas makes this useful still.

Comment: `_1` inferes the argument type, while you need to explicitly specify it for lambdas.

Comment: @Xeo: I still didn't understand it. All you're saying is that `_1` and  C++11 lambda work differently. But the question is, don't they achieve the same thing?

Comment: They would, if you could do `[](auto arg){ ... }`, but you can't.

Comment: Xeo: What exactly I can't? Please post me an example, showing what can't be done using lambda. You can write the type yourself, no?

Comment: Yes, you can write the type yourself, but if you intend to use it in generic code, that fails. You can't have generic lambda, but `boost::bind`'s placeholders are generic by design.